# swift: Assign function type to variable

Tags: swift, function, types

```
    struct System {
        var method: (() -> ())?
        var curMethod: Int

        init() {
            method = nil
curMethod = 0
        }

        mutating func method1() {
            curMethod = 1
        }

        mutating func method2() {
            curMethod = 2
        }
    }

    var sys = System()
    sys.method = System.method1
    sys.method!()
```

I get an error cannot assign value of type `(inout System) -> () -> ()' to type '(() -> ())?`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: struct System {
    var method: (() -> ())?
    var curMethod: Int
    
    init() {
        method = nil
        curMethod = 0
    }
    
    mutating func method1() {
        curMethod = 1
    }
    
    mutating func method2() {
        curMethod = 2
    }
}

var sys = System()
if let method1 = sys.method { sys.method = sys.method1 }
sys.method!()
print(sys.curMethod) //should be "1"

Comment: Now it's ok. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it's not really what I wanted to solve, sorry)) instead of calling sys.method1() I want to call sys.method() which should be == sys.method1()

Comment: sorry but I think you can'r assing a mutating method to a var

Comment: What's the intention for this code? It looks like it could be improved with `enum` and `protocol`

Comment: there are method1, method2, ..., methodn. And there's an array of certain methods, for example var m_arr = [System.method6, System.method9]. I want to make a loop 0 ..< m_arr.count and assign values from array to sys.method and call it.

Comment: You *could* do something [like this](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/3fc961f1426542fd7dfa5f83aa73d11c), but there's almost certainly a better way to solve whatever concrete problem you're facing.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your line `sys.method = System.method1` is wrong, as it would require `method1` to be a static function (like a class function) rather than an instance function, so it should be changed to `sys.method = sys.method1`. But this isn't allowed - the error is "error: partial application of 'mutating' method is not allowed".

If you make `System` a class (rather than a struct), it will work if you replace the `System.method1` with `sys.method1`.

The reason for this is that a `mutating func` is actually quite a lot more than a simple function under the hood - it is a curried function (curried with a compiler generated function) that effectively creates a new copy of the struct with the "new" value - hence, you A) can't access it it directly ("partial application is not allowed") and B) you can't assign it to a `()->()` variable.

Comment: `mutating func`s don't create a copy of the instance to operate, and that's exactly why there is the `"partial application is not allowed"`. Allowing that to be possible would effectively introduce reference semantics and shared mutability to structures, which is exactly what they're designed to prevent

Comment: `mutating` methods are actually fairly simple under the hood; the implicit `self` parameter is just `inout`, so is passed by reference. That reference is only guaranteed to be valid until the function call ends, so attempting to prolong that window of mutation by partially applying into a `() -> Void` is illegal. And in fact, there's actually currently a hole in the compiler where you can escape that reference with the curried instance method when accessed on the type: `var sys = System(); let curried = System.method1; let unsafe = curried(&sys); unsafe()`. That's UB. SE-0042 will fix it tho.

Answer (score 0):

So, there're 3 variants suggested by participants. Everything is working, and using class instead of struct seems to me less complicated.

```
struct System1 {

    var method: (() -> ())?
    var curMethod: Int

    init() {
        method = nil
        curMethod = 0
    }

    mutating func method1() { curMethod = 1 }
    mutating func method2() { curMethod = 2 }

}

struct System2 {

    var method: ((inout System2) -> ())?
    var curMethod: Int

    init() {
        method = nil
        curMethod = 0
    }

    mutating func callCurrentMethod() { method?(&self) }
    mutating func method1() { curMethod = 1 }
    mutating func method2() { curMethod = 2 }

}

class System3 {

    var method: (() -> ())?
    var curMethod: Int

    init() {
        method = nil
        curMethod = 0
    }

    func method1() { curMethod = 1 }
    func method2() { curMethod = 2 }

}

var struct1 = System1()
var struct2 = System2()
var class1 = System3()

print(struct1.curMethod)
let curried = System1.method1
let unsafe = curried(&struct1)
unsafe()
print(struct1.curMethod)

print(struct2.curMethod)
struct2.method = { $0.method1() }
struct2.callCurrentMethod()
print(struct2.curMethod)

print(class1.curMethod)
class1.method = class1.method1
class1.method!()
print(class1.curMethod)
```

Comment: The first one is undefined behaviour; don't actually use it. I only mentioned it in my comment above as it was an interesting hole in the compiler. Also note that the example with the `class` creates a retain cycle, you'll likely want to say `class1.method = { [weak class1] in class1?.method1() }` instead.

Comment: If I use class1.method = class1.method1, I can do the following: var methods = [System3.method2]; class1.method = methods[0](class1); How would you do the same with weak?

Comment: It wouldn't be pretty; something like `class1.method = { [weak class1, m0 = methods[0]] in guard let class1 = class1 else { return }; m0(class1)() }`. You could simplify with `unowned`, but you'll have to ensure you satisfy the preconditions that come with that. Although now that I think about it, a better way to avoid the retain cycle would be [just to store the curried function on the instance](https://gist.github.com/hamishknight/3df15b569bffbe6ca0b6d8113f820f91).

Comment: But again, I still maintain that there's probably a better way to solve whatever concrete problem you're facing. But without knowing what it is, it's impossible to say.